# MLP with keras for prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I try to create a neural network with keras (backened tensorflow). 
I have 4 Input and 2 Output variables:
not available

I want to do predictions to a Testset not available.

This is my Code:

```
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(7)
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("trainingsdata.csv", delimiter=";") 
X = dataset[:,0:4] 
Y = dataset[:,4:6]
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=4, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid')) 
model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid')) 
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform', activation='linear'))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=2) 
testset = numpy.loadtxt("testdata.csv", delimiter=";") 
Z = testset[:,0:4] 
predictions = model.predict(Z) 
print(predictions)
```

When I run the script, the accuracy is 1.000 after every epoch and I get as result always the same output for every input pair:

```
[-5.83297 68.2967] 
[-5.83297 68.2967] 
[-5.83297 68.2967] 
...
```

Has anybody an idea what the fault in my code is?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you could try to reshape your Y variable. From https://keras.io/models/model/ it said `outputs=[b1, b3, b3]` so I think the output should be set of values, not set of data. You can do that by transpose it.

Comment: Just to be sure you noticed it: you defined your SGD optimizer but you are actually not using it: you use Adaptative Momentum (Adam) during the compilation.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed it in my post. In my original script it is correct. Which optimizer would you prefer?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you normalize / standardize your data before feeding it to your model and then check if your model starts to learn.

Have a look at scikit-learn's [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

And look [into this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816718/keras-regression-using-scikit-learn-standardscaler-with-pipeline-and-without-pip) to learn how to correctly `fit_transform` your training data and only `transform` your test data.

There is also this tutorial that makes use of scikit-learn's data preprocessing pipeline: http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have read many tutorials of Dr Brownlee, but haven´t found this one!

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks have a tough time if the scale of the input variables is too different from each other.  Having 10, 1000, 100000 as the same inputs causes the gradients to collapse towards whatever the large value is.  The other values effectively don't provide any information.

One method is to simply rescale the input variables by a constant.  You can simply divide the 206000 by 100000.  Try getting all of the variables to be at around the same number of digits.  Large numbers are a bit harder than small numbers, for networks.

Comment: Thank you, it provides Information I could use now!! The results of my neural net are not accurate, but not always the same as before.

Comment: Happy to help out!