# standardizing data column-wise before using keras models

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I'm working with a large dataset whose data I want to standardize to use with a CNN.

Does keras have a quick utility to standardize a block of numbers column-wise that you can use inside a Sequential model? I'm asking this as i expect eventually the data to be used on-line so ideally this standardization feature could be used on incoming data, ie a trailing moving average of mean and std to normalize the incoming data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

col_names = ['Column' + str(x+1) for x in range(5)]
training_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10 **6, 50).reshape(-1,5), columns = col_names)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about online, but using `sklearn`'s `StandardScaler()` should do the right thing, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816718/keras-regression-using-scikit-learn-standardscaler-with-pipeline-and-without-pip), seems like the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

We can do from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
training_data[:]= StandardScaler().fit_transform(training_data.T).T
```